# virtual host apache in docker not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to raise my web in a docker container, the problem is that when I enter localhost it does not return me to my web but it shows me the directory with all the folders.

Virtual Host:

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/var/www/html/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /var/www/html/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/var/www/html/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Docker Compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  MyWeb:
    image: myweb:latest
    ports: 
      - 80:80
    environment:
        DB_NAME: auth
        HOST_DB: localhost
        USER_DB: root
        DB_PASSWORD: 1234
   
    command: 
      tail -f /dev/null
```

In the Docker File

I have the following lines

```
FROM php:5.4.33-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . .
COPY conf/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2ensite 000-default.conf
RUN service apache2 start
RUN a2ensite 000-default.conf
RUN service apache2 restart
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `WORKDIR /var/www/html/web`?

Comment: No, since the index is inside the web and I take it there from the virtual host.

Comment: you are running `COPY . .` can you please post a structure of the folders from the folder where there is the dockerfile? like `tree -L 3` or something like this